# Ribbon knot presentations

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 2-knots

Suppose $K$ is a $n$-knot, $n\geq 2$, which bounds two different ribbon disks $D_1, D_2$. These ribbon disks induce unique ribbon $(n+1)$-knots $K_1, K_2$ respectively. Is it known whether $K_1$ and $K_2$ are necessarily isotopic (obviously they must be if the ribbon disks are stably equivalent)?

For the $n=1$ case Nakanishi and Nakagawa have counterexamples to this in *On Ribbon Knots*, Math. Sem. Notes Kobe Univ. 5, 1982. However, their examples don't seem generalize in an obvious way to higher dimensional ribbon knots.

Comment: In "A Quick Trip Through Knot Theory" Fox gives examples 10 and 11. I presume these are examples of what you are speaking about. As I recall, the complements are mirror images of each other (maybe inverses). Kaneobu generalized the construction of examples 10,11,12, in the case $n=1$, and showed that all of the generalizations from 12 were twist-spun knots. In addressing the problem, I would try to generalize Kaneobu's technique.